# MVC When I add one table to EF Model.tt is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

When I add one table to EF Model.tt is empty.Please someone help me. It's very strange...
All table Class empty.

I use Visual Studio 2015 to develop

[image]

Comment: I want to ask what reason make the result.I am worry about when I add table to EF again. All the class table will empty...

Comment: try right clicking the tt file and run custom tool